# How to diagnose high scan count

Tags: sql-server

I'm curious how to go about diagnosing a high scan count in both a permanent and temporary table.  I have statistics turned on while running a stored proc, and I'm trying to figure out why the scan counts are so high.  I have the actual query plan, and SSMS has suggested a few indexes to add that were missing, but at this point nothing else.  What are some strategies I can look into to diagnose these issues?

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HksFRMLw-

```
SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
Table 'disbursement_check'. Scan count 9, logical reads 2281, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'cif'. Scan count 9, logical reads 490, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'voucher'. Scan count 9, logical reads 3067, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'cif_loan_relationship'. Scan count 9, logical reads 890, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'loanacct'. Scan count 45, logical reads 44124, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Workfile'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'loanacct_trans_history'. Scan count 1166870, logical reads 3654129, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table '#B17AB456'. Scan count 8, logical reads 1180568, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table '#BAD74620'. Scan count 2423794, logical reads 2486442, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table '#BBCB6A59'. Scan count 62661, logical reads 125306, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'loan_class'. Scan count 2, logical reads 4, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'lookup_table'. Scan count 2, logical reads 6, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'loanacct_detail'. Scan count 9, logical reads 1348, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 59160 ms,  elapsed time = 9877 ms.
Table '#TargetTransactions_________________________________________________________________________________________________0000000019E6'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

Comment: `I have the actual query plan, and SSMS has suggested a few indexes to add that were missing, but at this point nothing else` can you share execution plan as xml

Comment: @TheGameiswar Do you have a suggestion on how I would go about doing that, since it is 2.5M characters?

Comment: Try pastebin or https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ to publish actual execution plan (not estimated) - if it is possible.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean Added.  Had to remove the whitespace because that website only allows 2 MB.

Comment: @TheGameiswar Added

Comment: I recommend tuning TVF First.Can you try  `select *FROM dbo.getMyTransactions
 (
 @AssignedDealerIds,
 @DealerIds
 ) ` inserting the above result into a temp table and then use that in join

Comment: also try paying attention to warning hints ,you are joining mutiple columns which are not of same type,this results in scan,even if you have a correct index

Comment: @TheGameiswar Moving the getMyTransactions into a separate call beforehand seems to have no impact.  Execution time is the same, and there are still a ton of scans in those tables.

Comment: @TheGameiswar Where would I find these hints?

Comment: you can see in execution plan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151299/discussion-between-kyle-w-and-thegameiswar).

Answer (score 1):

Great question.

Based on some of the statistics, I would be inclined to think that there are some indexes, or lack of indexes, which are at fault here. The query plan may shed some light, though I don't have it as of the time of this posting.

I think that it would be safe to assume that the `loanacct_trans_history` table is the one for which indexes were suggested. Additionally, the 3 temp tables seem to be doing quite a bit of work as well...

The link below will help guide you to understand enough about indexes to answer your question.

> Please see this free 90-minute webinar from world-class DBA, Brent Ozar: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/10/think-like-engine-class-now-free-open-source/

Comment: Added the query plan.

Answer (score -1):

> I'm trying to figure out why the scan counts are so high.

and

> Table 'loanacct_trans_history'. Scan count 1166870, logical reads
>   3654129, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0,
>   lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. Table '#B17AB456'. Scan
>   count 8, logical reads 1180568, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0,
>   lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Because we don;t have (yet) actual execution plan, **best** assumption is that

[ 1 ] There is a high number of range scans (most likely) generated by some `Index Seek` with high number of `Execution Count` (maybe forced by `FORCESEEK` table hint)

[ 2 ] And/Or range scans or full scans generated by following combination of operators

```
... - Nested Loops (Join) - Any Data Access Operator
           |
           ---------------- Index Seek / *Scan loanacct_trans_history
```

In this case, I *assume* that `Estimated execution count` is 1 by actual/real `Execution Count` is high.

[ 3 ] Crop from execution plan that demonstrate points [ 1 ] and [ 2 ] and which is related with high scan count on table `loanacct_trans_history`:

> Table 'loanacct_trans_history'. Scan count 1166870, ...

[image]

It seems that following statements generates this high scan count:

```
INSERT INTO #TargetTransactions (Id, CreditServiceFeeTransactionId, CustomerCifNo, VoucherId)
 SELECT mt.transrefno, rt.CreditServiceFeeTransactionId, contact.cifno, rt.VoucherId
 FROM dbo.getMyTransactions
 (
 @AssignedDealerIds,
 @DealerIds
 ) mt
 JOIN loanacct_trans_history th ON th.transrefno = mt.transrefno
...
```

Few simple solutions: at the end of this statement I would try to add following **query** hints:

```
INSERT #T...
SELECT ...
...
OPTION(HASH JOIN)
-- Or OPTION(MERGE JOIN)
-- Or OPTION(HASH JOIN, MERGE JOIN)
```